# Error when creating crystal report in asp.net mvc2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, crystal-reports

I made a report using crystal report and in the page load I am writing this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
        crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon
            ("amit", "password", @"AMIT\SQLEXPRESS", "TestDB");
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
    }
```

and when runing the page I found this error.

CS0433: The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in both 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this tag in my web.config

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
```

and in my aspx page

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web,  Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

different version for the same assembly makes the conflict so I removed web.config tag and it runs very smooth.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste this `(Version=13.0.2000.0)` from web config to the default `ASPX` source code where you found different versions of Crystal Report and the error will be fixed.