# I can't drag and drop crystal reportviewer in web form 

Tags: crystal-reports, webforms

Hi
I've wired problem here.
I'm building a new fresh web application, and i want to use crystal report 2010 in one of my pages, the problem is that i can't drag and drop the crystal report viewer control .

Any idea why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

What specifically is the problem? Are you not seeing the control in your Toolbox or are you literally not able to drag the control from the Toolbox to your form?

If you are not seeing it but have added it to your control box see this post:

[how to enable crystal report viewer in Visual Studio 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbpowerpacks/thread/0be5c56d-2ac4-4827-ab72-643580c2fc64)

If you haven't added it as a control then you will have to do that first. Here is a quick start guide video that [explains it all](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wud4VtqpetU).

Comment: Thanks for answering .
I can see the control and i can drag it to the page but when i drop it nothing happens like i never did anything :( ..finally i use .Net 4 full not client profile

Comment: If you look at the source for the page do you see <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />

Comment: No tags added at all ... letterly nothing happend ... i can't add any of crystal report controls (data source,viewer,partviewer,..) just a report i can add ...

Comment: Very strange. Out of curiosity do you have trouble dragging anything else on the page? Also have you tried hand coding the tag instead of using the drag and drop just to see it works?

Comment: i can't add any of crystal report controls (data source,viewer,partviewer,..).. al other controls are good .
can you please give an aspx page to try it here ?

Comment: @BukHix : i tried hand coding the tag and got and error and solved it :  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736803/error-when-creating-crystal-report-in-asp-net-mvc2  
I still can't drag and drop .  
Now its working with another problem :S .... no icons in the toolbar .

Answer (score 0):

```
1st step: Add a Crystal report to your project.
2nd step: Then go to your web form and add a crystal report viewer control.
```

Just found out this solution from going around an asp.net project in Visual studio 2015. Hope this helps to anyone looking up.